# Executing code when none of the accesses are allowed in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to use `can` or `cannot` in Blade. For times when a user is not allowed to any of the items.
I want the appropriate message to be displayed when the user does not have update permission and deletion permission at the same time.
I tried to do this with the following command, but I noticed that the following command is executed even when it does not have access to one of the items. That is, when the user has permission to update, but does not have permission to delete, the command is also executed.

```
@cannot(['update-user','delete-user'])
     <span class="text-danger">You do not have administrative access</span>
@endcan
```

I have run my target with below command. But I don't think this is a good code. Is there a better way with cleaner and shorter coding?

```
@if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->cannot('update-user') && \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->cannot('delete-user') )
    <span class="text-danger">You do not have administrative access</span>
@endif
```

The question is about Laravel blades. The gate and related policies are defined.

Comment: You could use `auth()->user()` instead of `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` if you're simply looking for something shorter.

Comment: Thank you @D1__1 . This shortened my code a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Gate::none

```
@if(Gate::none(['update-user','delete-user']))
  <span class="text-danger">You do not have administrative access</span>
@endif
```

Or, you can add 2 blade directives, called cannotany and endcannotany. Just put your code in the boot method of AppServiceProvider:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
         Blade::directive('cannotany', function ($expression) {
            return "<?php if (app(\Illuminate\\Contracts\\Auth\\Access\\Gate::class)->none({$expression})): ?>";
        });

        Blade::directive('endcannotany', function ($expression) {
            return '<?php endif; ?>';
        });
    }
}
```

In your blade

```
@cannotany(['update-user','delete-user'])
     <span class="text-danger">You do not have administrative access</span>
@endcannotany
```